# How do I get the session_key for a permanent "offline_access" permission?

Tags: facebook, rest

I writing a server-side backend for a mobile app that will allow posting media to facebook. I need to post images to the user's profile.

I get the user to add the application + the user allows me to `offline_access`

From Facebook documentation I see that I need to pass the "session_key" on every api request I am doing (using the restful API).

I've forwarded the user to `prompt_permissions.php` but when he allows the offline_access - I don't get any signature/key.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

look for the cookie labeled:

`$APIKEY_session_key`

where $APIKEY is your API key.

this cookie contains the offline session key that you can use.

Comment: It doesn't work still.

I think I need to get an auth_token first and then direct the user for the login.php to generate a "session_key"

How do I get that AUTH_TOKEN ?

Comment: how are you going about getting the user to give permission to your app?